# PHP iterate each line but count them

Tags: php

So currently I have a contact text area  which have an icon only in the second and third line.

I was trying to add a condition to each line but seems like this is not the way, could someone help me out in achieving the result?

```
$getc = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM contactos WHERE id = 1");
$contacto = $getc->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$subject = $contacto['texto'];
foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $subject) as $line){
    for ($x = 1; $x <= 5; $x++) {
        if($x == 1){
             echo '<p style="margin-top:25px;">'.$line.'</p>';
        }else if($x == 2){
            echo '<p><i class="phone"></i> <span style="margin-left:15px;">'.$line.'</span></p>';
        }else if($x == 3){
            echo '<p><i class="mail"></i> <span style="margin-left:24px;">'.$line.'</span></p>';
        }else{
             echo '<p>'.$line.'</p>';
        }                       
    } 
}
```

Comment: It will be much easier if you posted the array. Right now we have no clue what you are doing

Comment: Or actually, post the string $subject instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to print only third and fourth line. We need to change your code a little bit:

```js
$getc = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM contactos WHERE id = 1");
$contacto = $getc->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$subject = $contacto['texto'];

$x = 1;
foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $subject) as $line){    
    if($x == 1){
         echo '<p style="margin-top:25px;">'.$line.'</p>';
    }else if($x == 2){
        echo '<p><i class="phone"></i> <span style="margin-left:15px;">'.$line.'</span></p>';
    }else if($x == 3){
        echo '<p><i class="mail"></i> <span style="margin-left:24px;">'.$line.'</span></p>';
    }else{
         echo '<p>'.$line.'</p>';
    }                       
    $x++; 
}
```

So as you see you need to count `foreach` iteration. Another loop inside it won't do anything good.

Comment: Great job ! this was exactly what I wanted. I knew that was not correct another for loop but could not figure out how I could perform it